# unable to resolve host address using wget or python requests

Tags: python, wget

I have a server and in my server when I try to get a website first page with `wget` I get an error:

```
emad@static:~$ wget poem.parsiblog.com
--2017-09-03 03:38:59--  http://poem.parsiblog.com/
Resolving poem.parsiblog.com (poem.parsiblog.com)... failed: Temporary failure in name resolution.
wget: unable to resolve host address ‘poem.parsiblog.com’
```

from my pc (not from that server) when I try to wget with a proxy and without a proxy in both I don't have any problem.

here is the `resolve.conf` file content:

```
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
nameserver 213.133.98.98
search 5.178.201.138.clients.your-server.de
```

and the result of 'dig poem.parsiblog.com' is:

```
; <<>> DiG 9.10.3-P4-Ubuntu <<>> poem.parsiblog.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached
```

Comment: What OS are your server running? What is the response of `$dig poem.parsiblog.com`. I think that you should remove the Python tag and add DNS related tags.

Comment: Does that dns server work? Try to query something else from it... You could also try some other dns server, for example google 8.8.8.8.

Comment: @gsi-frank I am using ubuntu 16.04 and the result of that command is ; <<>> DiG 9.10.3-P4-Ubuntu <<>> poem.parsiblog.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached

Comment: @StefanR when i ping other sites i have result

Comment: @EmadHelmi What are the results of `$ping google.com` and `$ping poem.parsiblog.com`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to be an issue with your DNS, try by doing this:

```
$ dig @213.133.98.98 poem.parsiblog.com +short
```

Should return the IP of `poem.parsiblog.com`, for example, when using servers from [dns.watch](https://dns.watch/) it returns this IP `5.144.129.195`:

```
$ dig @84.200.69.80 poem.parsiblog.com +short
5.144.129.195
```

As a fix, you could edit your /etc/resolv.conf and add something like:

```
nameserver 84.200.69.80
nameserver 4.2.2.2
```

If you are using DHCP, edit your `/etc/network/interfaces` so that changes could persist across reboots.

```
auto <interfacename>
iface <interfacename> inet dhcp
dns-nameservers 4.200.69.80 4.2.2.2
```